# Git fast-import and "from" command

Tags: git, cvs, git-fast-import

Trying to import a fast-export stream from cvs-fast-export. I have it working one shot, but now I need to do it incrementally since each import is taking hours. I have the incremental option working now, but it starts the stream with a "from refs/heads/master^0". This seems to match the fast-import documentation, but it crashes with a "fatal: Unsupported command: from refs/heads/master^0"

As I said, I can see that specific example in the documentation, so I don't know what is going wrong. Anyone know the correct syntax, or what I'm doing wrong?

Expected that running fast-import on the new stream would update the tags and branches to the new refs. In order to do that and keep the SHA hashes, it needs to know to point the previous for the new ref to the old one.

I've also tried the export-marks / import-marks, but a new stream still results in new sha.

Answer (score 0):

The 'from' command mentioned in the docs has to be a part of a commit and must match the commit description https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import#_commit

This means that you need to add the 'from refs/heads/master^0' statement to the very first commit of the incremental import. After the commit message and before the file contents of the commit.